# Website code does not wait for webservice call to complete execution

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asynchronous

I am having a website in which i am making a call to a web service. Following is the code snippet to make this call :

```
objResponce = objService.InvokeService(objReq);
```

InvokeService is the web method which returns result to website. This web method takes considerable amount of time before returning result. And before webservice can return the result to website, code in website continues to execute immediate next statement after the webservice call.

Comment: usually with async calls there is an event for when the call completes. find out and hook up this event to act on it.

Comment: currently there is no such event. So do you mean i need to write this event in a web service code? This websrvice code is written by my team. Can you give any code which i can use.